# Restsharp :The SSL connection could not be established

Tags: asp.net-core, restsharp, asp.net-core-2.1, client-certificates

An app is run on netcore2.1.5,win7.

1. I use restsharp to request the API and need to take client certificates, always return the error:

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
>   Authentication failed, see inner exception

The inner exception content:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090326): 接收到的消息异常，或格式不正确。

English version:

> "The message received is abnormal or not formatted correctly"

2. I user postman to request the API and take the same crt file and response the 
   result result.

My code on below:

```c#
string clientCertfile = @"E:\https\client.crt";
var client = new RestClient("https://apiserver/iocm/app/sec/v1.1.0/login");
X509Certificate2 certificates = new X509Certificate2(clientCertfile);
//X509Certificate2 certificates = GetMyX509Certificate(clientCertfile);
client.ClientCertificates = new X509Certificate2Collection(){ certificates };
client.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = 
    new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(OnRemoteCertificateValidationCallback);

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("appId", "rIsyJsnMtOrKfpSO90");
request.AddParameter("secret", "8v0fH0ztunjP1oXT");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

[postman test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZnFE.jpg)

Comment: ....it says "see inner exception". Did you follow its advice? What was the result of following that advice?

Comment: @mason   the inner exception content: {System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090326): 接收到的消息异常，或格式不正确。},means "The message received is abnormal or not formatted correctly"

Comment: The content type you provided is wrong. There shouldn't be a period. Look up what the correct content type is.

Comment: @mason  you mean "Content-Type"? ,I have fixed it ,still didn't work